# Spring Boot custom constraint validator with multiple values

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to add 2 values for my custom constraint validator because I have 2 feature flags:

```
 @JsonProperty(value = "name")
    @BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag(feature = FeatureFlag.AAA, values = {"aaa", "bbb"})
    @BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag(feature = FeatureFlag.BBB, values = {"ccc", "ddd"})
    private String parameter;
```

where:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = {BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlagValidator.class})
@Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag {

    String message() default "{validation.constraints.BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    FeatureFlag feature();

    String[] values() default {};
}
```

and implementation:

```
public class BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlagValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag, Object> {
    private final FeatureFlagService featureFlagService;

    private List<String> blocked;
    private FeatureFlag feature;

    @Override
    public void initialize(BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag constraintAnnotation) {
        blocked = Arrays.asList(constraintAnnotation.values());
        feature = constraintAnnotation.feature();
    }

@Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
```

But now I get compilation error "Duplicate annotation". How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should make your `BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag` repeatable. To do this:

1. Create a new "top-level" annotation:

```java
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RepeatableBlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag {
    BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag[] value();
}
```

2. Add @Repeatable to your BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag annotation

```java
...
@Repeatable(RepeatableBlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag.class)
public @interface BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag {
...
```

Then you should be able to add more than one `@BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag` annotation.

Comment: This is the way to go. Often the "container" annotation is an annotation called `List` that's nested inside the repeatable annotation itself. For instance: https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/jakarta/validation/constraints/NotNull.List.html

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your validator accept an array of feature flags.

```java
    @Constraint(validatedBy = {BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlagValidator.class})
    @Target({FIELD, PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @ReportAsSingleViolation
    public @interface BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag {
    
        String message() default "{validation.constraints.BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag.message}";
    
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    
        Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    
        FeatureFlag[] feature(); // <------ change here
    
        String[] values() default {};

}
```

Doing this will allow you to use it both ways:

```java
    @BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag(feature = {FeatureFlag.AAA, FeatureFlag.BBB}, values = {"aaa", "bbb"})
    private String parameter;

    @BlockedWithoutEnabledFeatureFlag(feature = FeatureFlag.AAA, values = {"aaa", "bbb"})
    private String parameter2;
```

Comment: But this doesn't allow only "aaa" and "bbb" for flag AAA, and only "ccc" and "ddd" for flag BBB. Repeatable annotations like in Yevhenii Semenov's answer are a much better option.

Comment: Good catch. That's right.